# Creating One time Plan using Stripe/Plan Facade

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

i want to create one time payment plan using Laravel/Plan Facade. i can create monthly, yearly plans but i don't know how to achieve one time payment plan as we can create one time payment plan when creating a product on stripe dashboard. below is my code for creating monthly, yearly, weekly or day but not lifetime/one-time payment.

```
$monthlyPlan = Stripe\Plan::create([
        "product" => $stripeProduct->id,
        "amount" => $request->input('amount_month'),
        "interval" => 'month',
        "currency" => $request->input('currency')
    ]);

    $yearlyPlan = Stripe\Plan::create([
        "product" => $stripeProduct->id,
        "amount" => $request->input('amount_year'),
        "interval" => 'year',
        "currency" => $request->input('currency')
    ]);
```

Comment: for `lifetime` you create your own plan and use stripe to charge with that amount . these plans for billing like subscription

Comment: how can i create that plan as above code?

Comment: don't create plan in stripe end create in your own database

Comment: can i create it through code? or it should be only on stripe dashboard, on stripe dashboard i can create one time plan but i want to create it through the stripe api

Answer (score 0):

You should use the new Prices API to model both your recurring and one off payments: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/migration/migrating-prices

Prices will allow you to create recurring payments, e.g.:

```
$monthlyPrice = $stripe->prices->create([
  'unit_amount' => $request->input('amount_month'),
  'currency' => request->input('currency'),
  'recurring' => ['interval' => 'month'],
  'product' => $stripeProduct->id,,
]);
```

and create one off Prices:

```
$oneOffPrice = $stripe->prices->create([
  'unit_amount' => $request->input('amount_month'),
  'currency' => request->input('currency'),
  'product' => $stripeProduct->id,,
]);
```

Comment: i am using "laravel/cashier": "^12.0", would that work?

Comment: it's saying call to a member function create on null

Comment: $stripeProduct = Stripe\Product::create([
                "name" => $request->input('name'),
                "type" => 'service'
            ]);
 
            $monthlyPlan = $stripeProduct->prices->create([
              'unit_amount' => $request->input('amount_month'),
              'currency' => $request->input('currency'),
              'recurring' => ['interval' => 'month'],
              'product' => $stripeProduct->id,
            ]);

Answer (score 0):

You can Create a Product with a price it will be by default one time payment

```php
Product::create([
    "id"=> "Product-id",
    "name"=>"Product-name",
    "default_price_data"=>array(
        "currency" => "usd",
        "unit_amount" => $request->price*100
    )
]);
```